# Can a component internally assign a ref to one of it's children?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I have a container component with `props.children` defined as:

```js
children?: ReactNode;
```

In my use-case, I need to set a ref to the first child so I can use it later for focus management when interaction starts.

Rather than having the consumer pass in the ref as a prop (as they are already populating `children`) I'm trying to set up the ref within the container component.

Here is my attempt, which has type errors:

```js
const firstChildRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
let count = 0;
const clones = React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
  const clone = React.cloneElement(child, [{
    ref: count === 0 ? firstChildRef : undefined
  }]);
  count++;
  return clone;
});
```

Is there a way for a component to internally assign a ref to one of it's `props.children`?

Comment: i feel this should not be the way. Take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html and see if you can work with this or not

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the children are having their refs forwarded (`React.forwardRef`), this should work

```js
const clones = React.Children
  .toArray(props.children)
  .map((child, idx) => {
    let props = {}
    if (idx === 0) {
      props = {
        ref: firstChildRef
      }
    }
    return React.cloneElement(child, props)
  });
```

Comment: This results in a TS error: `TS2769: No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following error. Argument of type 'string | number | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'...`

Comment: This is just a type mismatch. Type definitions for components is such a nightmare in React. Type assertions should be able to help you resolve the error, or just @ts-ignore it